# nhibernate xml files are not getting mapped automatically

Tags: nhibernate

```
-----working Code
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
        {
           ///     Connection String

        }).AddFile(@"D:\Test_MVC_Web\NHibernet_DAL\Mapping\departments.hbm.xml");
-------
above code is working fine for me but currently mapping is done manually i have to mapped xml file automatically at the time of configuration


  using (var session = _IUnitOfWork.Session)
            {
                IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetDepartmentDetails");


                query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(departments)));
                return query.List<departments>() as List<departments>;


            }
```

when i run above above code its giving me error named query 
because xml files are not getting mapped

Answer (score 0):

departments.hbm.xml file should be Embedded Resource

departments.hbm.xml-->properties-->Build Action-->Embedded Resource

Comment: i got the answer  => Configuration cfg = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
            {
                db.ConnectionString = "Server=172.19.63.116\\cmsserver2012;Database=UNONEW;Uid=sa;Pwd=sql@2012;";
                db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            });
              //  Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
             //   cfg.Configure();
                //D:\Projects\UNO MVC N EW\UNO_MVC_Web\NHibernet_DAL\XmlMapping\MCompany.hbm.xml
                cfg.AddFile(@"D:\Projects\UNO MVC N EW\UNO_MVC_Web\NHibernet_DAL\XmlMapping\MCompany.hbm.xml");

Comment: in above code files are getting mapped but i hve to configure each file every tym is there any wayi can directly mappded all the hbm files